# Use specific syntax with Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this:

[image]

So now, what I want is this logic but I don't write everytime in each cellul :

- In B3 : =SI(A3>B1;1;0)
- In C3 : =SI(A3>C1;1;0)
- In D3 : =SI(A3>D1;1;0)
- In B4 : =SI(A4>B1;1;0)
- In C4 : =SI(A4>C1;1;0)
- In D4 : =SI(A4>D1;1;0)

I just need to retrieve each cellul column A and compare to each cellul ligne 1

Someone can help me

Comment: Yes, i'm using sheets

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A5>B1:D1; 1; 0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF($A3>B2,1,0)
```

Once the absolute reference is set just drag the formula to the whole row:

[image]

Once done you just need to drag the formula down and it will be applied as you like to all the remaining cells:

[image]